# Writing to existing CSV or Excel File in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, npoi

I want to be able to continually update a CSV or Excel xlsx file, maybe using NPOI or anything else really. I just need to accomplish the below.

Example of my code is below, I am capturing timings. The code is using Selenium. Each time the test is run, I need those timings to be exported to an existing excel/csv file that I will have stored on my C: drive. I dont want to overwrite existing cells, instead I want to add the new timings on the next blank row each time.

My existing excel file, will have just 3 header columns. These will be titled "Date Of Test", "Name of Test", "Elapsed Time"

```
        [Test]
    public void TimeForWebPagesToLoad()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var dateTime = currentDate.ToString();

        var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        sw1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time for Google to load is {0}", sw1.Elapsed);

        var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
        sw2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time for Facebook to load is {0}", sw2.Elapsed);

        /*TODO code to write the Elapsed time into excel
        WriteToExcelMethod(dateTime, "Google Perf Test", sw1.Elapsed)
        WriteToExcelMethod(dateTime, "Facebook Perf Test", sw2.Elapsed)
        */

        Assert.IsTrue(sw1.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Assert.IsTrue(sw2.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason in inserting data into xlsx file intead of simpler file like csv?

Comment: No there is not. I just need a grid like file type to store these timings into. I've never worked with CVS. If that is easier. Can you show an example of how the above can be accomplished

Comment: I actually just viewed a couple CSV examples. That wouldnt work. I need the recordings to be in a grid for better readability.

Comment: You can open csv file using excel or other application like LibreOffice Calc

Comment: Then CSV would be fine

Comment: I updated the original post to include CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that would work:

```
public static void WriteToExcelMethod(DateTime dt, string str, TimeSpan ts)
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.csv";
    string line = String.Format(@"""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}""", dt, str, ts);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Is there anyway to format the CSV so that when I open it in excel, the columns are expanded to show the largest value. Currently I have to open the file, and manually double click the column line to expand it so I can read each cell

Comment: CSV file (Comma Separated Values), by definition, only has the values. It knows nothing about format. In Excel, however, you can select all and double-click on any column divider to accommodate widest values.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV file:

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("pippo.csv", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", DateTime.Now, "Google Perf Test", ws1.Elapsed));
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", DateTime.Now, "Facebook Perf Test", ws2.Elapsed));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **File** Class
Here is a small snippet which can be used

```
        var csv = new StringBuilder();

        var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue);
        csv.AppendLine(newLine);

        File.AppendAllText(fileUrl, csv.ToString());
```

I hope this should work for you.

Comment: What if `firstValue` has a comma in it? What happens then?

Comment: Didn't thought of that condition. Thank you for reminding. I believe the solution given after me takes into account a condition having a comma.

Comment: No, none of the solutions yet properly deal with the fact that a delimiter may be in any of the variables. The solution is to use a library that's already set up to handle these sorts of issues, rather than reinvent the wheel.